# Recursive Descent-Based Calculator Stack Overflow

Tags: antlr, recursive-descent

**TL;DR:**

My calculator grammar relies on recursive descent to nest parentheses groups inside each other, but too many nested parens (around 20) causes a stack overflow.  How can I fix this?  Is there a way to make the problem more flat?

**Longform:**

It wasn't long ago that - my head stuck deeply into small scale embedded systems - no person with half a brain should run into a stack overflow.  Now humbled by a much more abstract task, I come here for advice.

The motivating project is a calculator for Android.  The current calculators are glaringly insufficient in so many ways, but I didn't bring my soapbox today, so I'll just get straight to the problem I'm running into: stack overflows!

Specifically, when the user creates too many nested parentheses groups, including functions and such.  This occurs because my calculator relies on an `ANTLR` grammar, meaning it uses recursive descent.  Conveniently, this allows for it to run continuously through PEMDAS, allowing calculation of nested functions and parentheses easy.  But!  I found that - depending on the phone - pressing the parens button 20 or so times caused a crash, caused by a stack overflow stemming from a call stack about 100 function calls deep, a natural result of the recursive descent method.

I know, flat is better than nested, but 4 of the levels (functions) it goes down through are completely necessary, and a couple of the other levels make my life logarithmically easier.  Even removing these levels wouldn't solve the problem: the user would still be able to cause the system to crash within a couple minutes.  Having a "too many parens!" error message is bad (its something one of the other calculators would do).  Also, I use the AST output to format the input string to make it rill pretty-like, so pre-calculation of parens groups would like make the whole system a bit too complicated.

So, question:

Even asking this question seems silly, but: is there a way to implement a grammar in ANTLR that can parse and interpret complicated and deeply nested expressions without exploding the call stack?

The grammar:

```
grammar doubleCalc;

options {
    language = Java;
    output = AST;
//  k=2;
}

// Calculation function.
prog returns [double value]
    :   e=addsub EOF {$value = $e.value;}
    ;

addsub returns [double value]
    :   e=muldiv {$value = $e.value;}
        (   PLUS^ e=muldiv {$value += $e.value;}
        |   MINUS^ e=muldiv {$value -= $e.value;}
        )*
    ;

muldiv returns [double value]
    :   e=power {$value = $e.value;} 
        (   MUL^ e=power {$value *= $e.value;}
        |   DIV^ e=power {$value /= $e.value;}
        )*
    ; 

power returns [double value]
    :   e = negate {$value = $e.value;} 
        (   POW^ f=power {$value = java.lang.Math.pow($value, $f.value);}   
        )?
    ; 

negate returns [double value]
    :   (   MINUS^ neg = atom {$value = -$neg.value;}
        |   neg = atom {$value = $neg.value;}
        )
    ;

atom returns [double value]
    :   LOG10^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = java.lang.Math.log10($e.value);} 
    |   LOG8^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = java.lang.Math.log10($e.value)/java.lang.Math.log10(8.0);} 
    |   LOG2^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = java.lang.Math.log10($e.value)/java.lang.Math.log10(2.0);} 
    |   LN^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = java.lang.Math.log($e.value);} 
    |   ASIN^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = Math.asin(Math.PI*(($e.value/Math.PI) \% 1));}//com.brogramming.HoloCalc.Trig.asin($e.value);} 
    |   ACOS^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = Math.acos(Math.PI*(($e.value/Math.PI) \% 1));}
    |   ATAN^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = Math.atan(Math.PI*(($e.value/Math.PI) \% 1));}
    |   SIN^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = Math.sin(Math.PI*(($e.value/Math.PI) \% 1));} 
    |   COS^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = Math.cos(Math.PI*(($e.value/Math.PI) \% 1));} 
    |   TAN^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = Math.tan(Math.PI*(($e.value/Math.PI) \% 1));}
    |   ASIND^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = Math.asin(Math.PI*(($e.value/180f) \% 1));}//com.brogramming.HoloCalc.Trig.asin($e.value);} 
    |   ACOSD^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = Math.acos(Math.PI*(($e.value/180f) \% 1));}
    |   ATAND^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = Math.atan(Math.PI*(($e.value/180f) \% 1));}
    |   SIND^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = Math.sin(Math.PI*(($e.value/180f) \% 1));} 
    |   COSD^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = Math.cos(Math.PI*(($e.value/180f) \% 1));} 
    |   TAND^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = Math.tan(Math.PI*(($e.value/180f) \% 1));}
    |   SQRT^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = (double) java.lang.Math.pow($e.value, 0.5);} 
    |   CBRT^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = (double) java.lang.Math.pow($e.value, 1.0/3.0);} 
    |   ABS^ '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = (double) java.lang.Math.abs($e.value);}
    // Numbers
    |   n = number {$value = $n.value;}
    |   '(' e=addsub ')' {$value = $e.value;}
    ;

number returns [double value]
    :   PI {$value = java.lang.Math.PI;}
    |   EXP {$value = java.lang.Math.E;}
    |   INT {$value = (double) Double.parseDouble($INT.text.replaceAll(",", ""));}
    |   DOUBLE {$value = Double.parseDouble($DOUBLE.text.replaceAll(",", ""));}
    ;

LN  :    'ln';
LOG10   :   'log10';
LOG8    :   'log8';
LOG2    :   'log2';
SIN :   'sin';
COS :   'cos';
TAN :   'tan';
ASIN    :   'asin';
ACOS    :   'acos';
ATAN    :   'atan';
SINH    :   'sinh';
COSH    :   'cosh';
TANH    :   'tanh';
ASINH   :   'asinh';
ACOSH   :   'acosh';
ATANH   :   'atanh';
SIND    :   'sind';
COSD    :   'cosd';
TAND    :   'tand';
ASIND   :   'asind';
ACOSD   :   'acosd';
ATAND   :   'atand';
SINHD   :   'sinhd';
COSHD   :   'coshd';
TANHD   :   'tanhd';
ASINHD  :   'asinhd';
ACOSHD  :   'acoshd';
ATANHD  :   'atanhd';
PI  :   'pi';
IM  :   'i';
EXP :   'e';
ABS :   'abs';
FACT    :   'fact';
SQRE    :   'sqre';
CUBE    :   'cube';
SQRT    :   'sqrt';
CBRT    :   'cbrt';
POW : '^';
PLUS : '+';
MINUS : '-';
MUL : ('*');
DIV : '/';
BANG    :   '!';
DOUBLE: ('0'..'9' | ',')+ '.'('0'..'9')* ;
INT :   ('0'..'9' | ',')+ ;
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;
PERCENT
    :   '%';
EOF :   '<EOF>' {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

Comment: i think this is the first time i have seen a question related to stack-overflow on Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this nice technique from Keith Clarke:

http://antlr.org/papers/Clarke-expr-parsing-1986.pdf

ANTLR v4 uses a variation.

Comment: ANTLR 4 still uses recursion for expressions like `'(' expr ')'`, so it would still face recursion limits. However, the individual stack frames tend to be smaller so deeper nesting is probably possible. The current weak point is the recursion in the internal `closure` operation; if replaced with a worklist I would expect *much* deeper expression nesting is possible with V4 than V3.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like ANTLR v4 is the way to go according to Ter's answer, however another approach would be to scan the input string yourself and recursively pick out and replace the lowest parenthetical groups with their calculated value.

I would create my own TokenStream which buffers tokens, looking for ')'.  When it sees that, search backwards for the '('.  Take that sequence of tokens and feed it to your parser to get the double value of that expression.  Define a custom Token class that can hold a double in it, and a special token type to designate a computed result, and stick that into your stream where the parens used to be.  Modify your grammar to handle that new token by returning the embedded double.

In this way you actually eliminate the need for `'(' e=addsub ')'` in your grammar.  All of those would be replaced by a rule that matches your special token and returns the value embedded in it.

Also you are building a tree with your grammar but given the actions in your rules it looks like you're calculating the expression immediately.  Assuming you're not actually using the tree, you should eliminate the tree building annotations and get rid of the `output=AST` option.

Comment: Indeed, it would seem that I don't need the AST output, but I failed to mention in my first post that I use the output AST to format the input calculation string.  Mostly, this allows me to make the exponent groups to be superscripted.  Thanks for the advice!